# Jquery: Get Head and Body Tag Contents from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I am having a string like below:

```
<head>
    This is the Head
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p> Body Content <br /></p>
            <p>&nbsp; Hello World <br /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

It is having both head and body tags. Now I want the contents of head tag and body tag using jquery. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried so far? It certainly is possible, but you might want to give some more background so we can suggest better alternative approaches.

Comment: improved formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Well suppose your string variable is "s" so the code is:

```
var html = document.createElement('html');
html.innerHTML = s;

var head = $(html).find('head:first');
var body = $(html).find('body:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here parse the string to html object and then you will be able to access the elements.

Here is code for the same

```js
var str = "<head>This is the Head</head><body><div><div><p> Body Content <br /> </p><p>&nbsp; Hello World <br /></p> </div></div></body>";


//This will parse the string to HTML
var htmlString = $.parseHTML(str);

//To get the Body content
console.log(htmlString[1].innerHTML);

//To get the HTML Tag Content
console.log(htmlString[0].data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15130381)

Comment: Thanks @JimHawkins . Will take care in future.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the regular expression as well, with basic and simple and one more benefit of using that is you can get any other html as well. Please find the code below :**

```js
var html = '<head>\
    This is the Head\
</head>\
<body>\
    <div>\
        <div>\
            <p> Body Content <br /></p>\
            <p>&nbsp; Hello World <br /></p>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
</body>';
    
var reg = /\<head[^>]*\>([^]*)\<\/head/m;
var head = html.match( reg )[1];

var reg2 = /\<body[^>]*\>([^]*)\<\/body/m;
var body = html.match( reg2 )[1];

document.getElementById("Head").innerHTML = head;
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = body;
```

```css
.head{
  border:1px solid red;  
}
.body{
  border:1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
<h1>
Heading
</h1><br />
<div id="Head">
</div>
</div> <br />
<div class="body">
<h1>
Body
</h1> <br />
<div id="body">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you considered trying these jquery expressions.

```
$('head').html();
$('body').html();
```

for combined text the following jquery expressions.

```
$('head').text();
$('body').text();
```